# display formatted data from database to richtextbox

Tags: c#

I made a program that can add formatted (change font,size and colour) data using a richtextbox into my MS Access Database,  there is also a normal text box to store the topics which is loaded to a listbox when you click on a topic in the listbox it is supposed to display the formatted text in another richtextbox, it displays the plain text perfectly but as soon  as a topic is clicked with formatted text it displays how the text was formatted:

```
 {\rtf\ansi\ansicpg 1252\deflang7177{\f0\fnil\fcharset 0 Microsoft Sans serif;}}
{\colortbl;\red0\green255\blue128;}
\viewkind4\uc 1\pard\cf1\fs17 now\cf0\par
}
```

My code:

```
private void listItem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\SumWizz.accdb";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring);
            string query = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Name = '" + listItem.Text + "'";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                // reads the data and fills the combo box and listbox

                while (reader.Read())
                {


                    string Sdetail = reader.GetString(2);
                    richItem.Text = Sdetail;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
```

I have changed richItem (my richtextbox) to richItem.rtf = Sdetail;
Then it displays the formatted text perfectly but when topic selected with plain text it says format invalid, I have to use it in 2 more places. is there a check I can do to first check if the text has rtf properties or any other way to get it to display both plain and formatted text?

Answer (score 0):

Rich text seems to always starts with `{\rtf` (I may be wrong. But it seems like a fair assumption). So it you check for that, you'll be able to decide.

Please see this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddc32982-84dd-4fe8-8d6e-90a93fc18b44/is-there-a-way-to-detect-whether-or-not-a-string-contains-text-with-rtf-formatting) for a convenient extension method to do this.

> Code from msdn forum

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the DataFormat string of the text.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Text to check.</param>
/// <returns>Value from the <see cref="DataFormats"/> enumeration.</returns>
public static string GetDataFormat(this string text)
{
    // First validate the text
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return System.Windows.DataFormats.Text;

    // Return right data
    if (text.StartsWith(@"{\rtf")) return System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf;

    // Return default
    return System.Windows.DataFormats.Text;
}
```

Usage:

```
var format = myString.GetDataFormat();

if (format == System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf)
{
     // process RTF text
}
else 
{
    // process plain text
}
```

Comment: thank you now i'm getting an error saying Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class i added a new class,      public static class Class1
    {
        public static string GetDataFormat(this string text)
        {
            // First validate the text
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text;

            // Return right data
            if (text.StartsWith(@"{\rtf")) return System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Rtf;

            // Return default
            return System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text;
        }
        }
    }

Comment: okay after i called the method it is still not solving my problem i have

Comment: I updated the usage of the extension. Please use the return value to decide whether the text is RTF or not.